# How to change a brach name on git even after raising a merge request?

Tags: git, github

The brach name has a . in it. So want to rename the branch.

Any commands to do it or do I need to create a new branch and again push all the code there and raise PR again?

Comment: there is no such thing as "renaming a branch" in git alone, it is 100% equivalent to create a new branch and deleting the old one. Ragarding github's Pull Requests, AFAIK there is no way to change the source branch on an existing PR, you would have to open a new PR for the new branch. The code would be 100% the same, if you want to keep a link to the comments or history of the previous PR you would have to mention a link to it in the comments or something like that.

Comment: @LeGEC *it is 100% equivalent to create a new branch and deleting the old one* perhaps on the conceptual level, but not in practice. Using `git branch -m` to rename a branch preserves the reflog; creating a new branch and deleting the old one does not preserve it.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, creating a new branch would be best.

Create a new branch without the '.'
Take a pull from that old branch into the new one (all your changes will be synced into your new branch), now raise the PR with that new branch and you can delete the old one.